# Importing a database table with > 250 Mio. rows using Laravel

Tags: sql-server, laravel, eloquent

I have a MSSQL Database with 286.536.323 rows. This is more of an aggregation of multiple databases. No indices or keys defined. Now I need to import this database to an existing MYSQL database.

Currently i am bulk inserting the data, by fetching data from the MSSQL database in chunks of 1000 (limit + offset) and inserting it to the MYSQL database.

In the beginning, it is quite fast (approx 5k/s), but the longer it loaded (approx. 11.000.000 entries), the slower it becomes (1k every 2s). And i feel speed is decreasing.

I stopped my script and turned off the insert part and found out, that even reading the data takes quite long. I have the feeling, that the bigger the offset is, the longer it takes to fetch the data.

This is the query i am currently using to load the data:

```sql
select * from 
(select [id] as [id], ..., row_number() over (order by (select 0)) as row_num 
from [invoice_items]) as temp_table 
where row_num between 11453001 and 11458000 order by row_num
```

It is generated by a query builder in a Laravel Project.

```php
$invoiceItems = OldInvoiceItem::limit($chunkSize)->offset($i)->get()
```

What can I do do improve the speed of my undertaking?

---

Edit:
I have sufficient hardware to work with (100GB Ram + modern 6 core CPU)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are ordering by a calculated value which is not stored in the table, and then calculating an offset into that list. The DBMS has to calculate the order of all the items you are skipping over each time. (Looking at your query, it's not even clear that your sort order is stable, and not giving you the same row in different batches.)

Instead, choose a stored column, with an index - preferably the "Clustered Index" (which is the order rows are stored on disk). Using that in an `ORDER BY` and standard `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` will probably be enough to make use of the index:

```
SELECT *
FROM invoice_items
ORDER BY id
OFFSET 11453001 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 1000 ROWS ONLY;
```

Alternatively, use a `WHERE` clause to select specific ranges of `id` - the batches might not be perfectly equal in size if there are gaps in the id sequence, but you're guranteed to hit the index.

```
SELECT *
FROM invoice_items
WHERE id BETWEEN 11453001 AND 11454000;
```

It will probably also be more efficient to by-pass the Eloquent ORM for this, and just work with raw SQL and simple array results - iterate the rows, generate an `INSERT` statement, and repeat.

Comment: @N69S Thanks for the edit, but "unstored" wasn't meant to be "unsorted", it was meant to be "not stored". I've reworded to be more explicit.